# Storing API requests database vs memcached

Tags: php, database, laravel, memcached

I am in a situation where I can't make up my mind. I have a client management system (Whmcs) that our company uses to sell web hosting, vps,... At the moment I am writing a new standalone client interface that uses the API of WHMCS to retrieve the client's details, invoices, support, tickets and products. All other logic happens in the new application (Configuring products, paying invoices,...)

These API requests happen on a private network, speed is not the issue here. But, I would like to store them either in Memcached or in a seperate database to reduce these requests to the bare minimum.

If I work with a database, I would work with some kind of webhook that the WHMCS will call if, for example, when a user has a new invoice. This would be send to the webhook and the database gets updated only if something changes in WHMCS. The only downside I see here is that some of the data is present on two systems and a lot of events and webhooks will have to be written to achieve this.

The other solution is using our memcached cluster and store the needed API requests there, if a user logs in, the data that is needed gets returned then stored in memcached. This way there will only be one API request untill something has changed. This way is relatively easy to achieve, example below:

```
    public function getInvoices($status = null)
    {
        if (!Cache::has('invoices_' . $status . $this->id)){
            $data = $this->fetchInvoices($this->id, $status);
            Cache::put('invoices_' . $status . $this->id, $data, 30);
        }

        $data = Cache::get('invoices_' . $status . $this->id);

        //Check if user owns the invoices
        if (Gate::denies('owns-data', $this->id)){
            abort(401);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I've come up with a solution. The idea is to keep the customers data and the application data in separate databases. The app database holds some basic user information, blog posts, forum data,... The second database is the WHMCS database itself where I pull out all the needed data for invoices, products, support tickets,...

Any updates that need to be send to WHMCS (Invoice payment, upgrading products,...) happens through the API. This way WHMCS can perform its own logic with the incoming data.

A second part that I have implemented is a robust, custom caching system that limits the API queries made to our infrastructure. (Openstack, cPanel,...) The idea is pretty simple: the backend of the app listens for Create, Update, Read and Delete that are included in function names with a `__call` method.

For example:

```
$data = array(
    'hostname'  => $r['host'],
    'username'  => $r['username'],
);

Cpanel::listAddonDomain($data);
```

This lists all the addon domains the user has added to their hosting account in cPanel. To reduce the amount of requests This needs to be cached until the user has made a change or he has been logged out.

First, there is some logic that checks if the user owns the cPanel account then it splits up `listAddondomains` into an array, if the first key equals to `list, read or get` the data gets cached with a tag that defines the user that the data belongs to:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    // Check if the user owns the account
    if(Gate::denies('owns-data', $this->search($this->getProducts(), 'username', $arguments['username'])[0]['clientid']))
    {
        if ($request == 'api'){
            return Api::respondNotAllowed('Not Allowed!');
        }

        abort(404);
    }

    $nameSplit = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $name);

    // Check for arguments to flush the cache
    if($nameSplit[0] == 'create' || $nameSplit[0] == 'delete' || $nameSplit[0] == 'add' || $nameSplit[0] == 'install')
    {
        Cache::tags(['cpanel', $arguments['username']])
            ->flush();
    }

    // If is already present in cache
    if(Cache::tags(['cpanel', $arguments['username']])->get($name . '_' . Auth::user()->id))
    {
        return Cache::tags(['cpanel', $arguments['username']])
            ->get($name . '_' . Auth::user()->id);
    }

    // Do the query
    try{

        $data = $this->send($arguments, $this->getClass($nameSplit), $name);
        $response = Api::respondSuccess($data);

    }catch (Exception $e){
        return Api::respondInternalError($e);
    }

    Cache::tags(['cpanel', $arguments['username']])
        ->put($name . '_' . Auth::user()->id, $response, $this->cacheTime);

    return $response;
}

private function send($arguments, $className, $functionName)
{
    $do = new $className($arguments);
    return $do->$functionName();
}
```

The code above is reduced to its bare minimum. It would be too long to post here, but you'll get the picture.

Now what about purging the cache at the right times? Let's say a user creates a new addon domain, the existing cache needs to be purged.

```
$data = array(
    'hostname'  => $r['host'],
    'username'  => $r['username'],
    'domain'    => $r['domain']
);

Cpanel::createAddonDomain($data);

$nameSplit = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', 'createAddonDomain');

if($nameSplit[0] == 'create' || $nameSplit[0] == 'delete' || $nameSplit[0] == 'add' || $nameSplit[0] == 'install')
{
    Cache::tags(['cpanel', $arguments['username']])
        ->flush();
}
```

If the addon domain creation was successful, the cache gets flushed for that cPanel account.

I've been testing this for a week now and it works like a charm. I've seen page loading times go down a lot with the cache enabled and getting the data directly from the WHMCS database.

Next stop, rewriting all the laravel views to a standalone Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea to create a new client interface ontop of WHMCS!

I would not go the first route with hooks and having data in two systems. The feeling is that sooner or later systems will come out of sync and you can't trust the data in your database.

Before you start optimizing and caching, have you tried using API for "source of truth" all the time? It might be that your application is quick enough even if you hit the API every time you need data?

In that case your application will be very simple and never have to worry about caching and invalidating cache data. For example, what happens if you have cached information about an invoice for 30 minutes. Then the invoice is changed by admin inside WHMCS or by the system it self. Now your application will be out of sync for 30 minutes because it doesn't know the invoice has changed.

Comment: Last week i've started experimenting with hooking the WHMCS database directly with the new client interface. This works great! However the laravel app will do no writing to the database, only reads. These queries get stored in memcached with the Cache::remember() function. All write happen trough the WHMCS api so that WHMCS can handle all the writes to avoid conflicts. The laravel app has it's own database to interact with to store basic user information and all the forum/community data. This setup allows me to work fast and I have all the freedom that I did not have before when using WHMCS.

Comment: Any plan to release that @Odyssee, need to do the same to replace my  system. Don't plan to update to the new pricing plans.